# Output Array based on Criteria

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array. The code below outputs one entire column.

```
<?php       
for ( $row = 1; $row <$arrCSV; $row++ ) {
    echo ''.$arrCSV[$row]['6'].'';  
}
?>
```

How would I put an "IF" statement to only display the rows the have "CAT" in "$arrCSV[$row]['4']"

I am not sure if it is an IF statement?

Comment: please give me your first row(columns) in csv file?

Comment: Integer is less that array? That's an interesting concept...

Comment: @M42 - Sorry, still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is the best function for determining if a particular substring exists (**EDITED** according to comments below):

```
$foundOneMatchingRow = FALSE;
foreach ($arrCSV as $row) {
  if (strpos($row['4'], 'CAT') !== FALSE) {
    $foundOneMatchingRow = TRUE;
    echo $row['6'];
  }
}
if (!$foundOneMatchingRow) {
  echo "I couldn't find a matching row!":
}
```

I have changed the `for` loop to a `foreach` because for this particular task, it is less confusing and more readable.

Comment: This works great. Can you put an ELSE in this statement to display a message if there is nothing? or is that complex

Comment: @Arthor You mean one message at the end if there are no matching rows? Or display a message for each row that is output?

Comment: I mean if there were no matching rows.

Comment: @Arthor You just need a boolean flag initialised at `FALSE`, and set it to `TRUE` and soon as you find a matching row. Then if it is still `FALSE` after the loop, output a message. See edit above

Comment: Right.. This is great. Tonight I will break it down and learn this... I love PHP... But I am not the most logical person. Hence I need to practice. Thank you ever so much DaveRandom.

Comment: Hello, On the [6] array, how would one put a criteria on that part of the array. I would like it to show ONLY if there is more than 4 chars in the line. Thank you

Comment: Try changing `if (strpos($row['4'], 'CAT') !== FALSE) {` to `if (strpos($row['4'], 'CAT') !== FALSE && strlen($row['6']) > 4) {`

Comment: Ok. I will try it an let you know.

Comment: - I have this code thanks to you now :) `foreach ($arrCSV as $row) 
if ($val == "All Videos" && strlen($row['5']) > 4)
{
echo $row['6'];
}`  Is there a way to skip the first line? Do not get me wrong. I have been looking as I want to lean and I have been chopping your code to see how it work. I have learned some good stuff. e.g. `&&` means (AND), `||` means or. Getting there :)

Comment: Assuming that `$arrCSV` is numerically indexed, you can just do this: `foreach ($arrCSV as $key => $row) if ($key && $val == "All Videos" && strlen($row['5']) > 4) { echo $row['6']; }` - but where does `$val` come from?

Comment: `$val = $_GET['id'];` I get the info from the URL. E.g. $VAL could = dogs, and it will only so info about dogs.

Comment: Great. Thank you - is `$key` anything special or just a normal var?

Comment: I see - it does seem like an odd place to put this comparison then, since you are doing a static comparison and not relating it to the data in `$arrCSV` - at worst you could rewrite the same code as `if ($val == "All Videos") foreach ($arrCSV as $key => $row) if ($key && strlen($row['5']) > 4) { echo $row['6']; }` - this means that you only have to do the check once and if it fails you don't even enter the loop.

Comment: That is Great.. I had that logic in mind but I was not sure how to put it together... Thank you very much. I will try to write it with out looking at your code to learn the construction. Thank you

Comment: `$key` is just the index of the value in the array - and indexed arrays start at `0`, so the first row will evaluate to `FALSE` if you treat it as a boolean, but every other row will be `TRUE`. This makes it a nice easy way to check if it's the first row or not - but it does rely on the first row having an index of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($row = 1; $row < $arrCSV; $row++) {
    if (strpos($arrCSV[$row]['4'], 'CAT') !== false) {
        echo $arrCSV[$row]['6'];
    }
}
```

Is this what you are looking for? Not sure if I understand the question.

Also you say `$row < $arrCSV` but `$arrCSV` is an array object, not an integer. Are you sure the provided code works as you say it does?

Comment: I suppose  he means `for ($row=1, $l=count($arrCSV); $row<$l; $row++)`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arrCSV as $row) {
    if (strpos($row[4], 'CAT') !== false) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code try this.

```
$result = array();
foreach($arrCSV as $key => $value) {
  if($value['4'] == 'CAT') {          
    $result[] = $value;
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This outs put all, but I got the idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(array_filter($arrCSV,function($row) { return (strpos($row[4],'CAT') !== FALSE); } ) as $row) { 
    echo ''.$row['6'].'';   
}
```

Assumes checking all entries in $arrCSV

Comment: @ Mark Baker First of all thank you,  I have put the code into DW, there is a syntax error. I have been look but I cannot see anything missing.

Comment: Depends on the version of PHP youu're running: this code takes advantage of anonymous functions (or "closures") only available in PHP 5.3.0 or above... if you are running an appropriate version of PHP, what's the syntax error?

Comment: It does not state in DW. it just has the line in red. But I do not have 5.3, that I am sure of. thank you